# How to use jobService spring batch admin with autowired annotation spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I use **`Spring-Boot`** for my app, and I want to **`Autowired`** `jobService` of **`Spring Batch Admin`** to manage **batch job** myself.
But when i use this

```
@Autowied
Jobservice jobService;
```

It throws exception

```
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.admin.service.JobService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

How can I fix this exception. Am I need to configure any thing about jobService.
I researched and try this

```
@Bean
public JobService jobService() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobServiceFactoryBean factory = new SimpleJobServiceFactoryBean();
    return factory.getObject();
}
```

But seem like not work and it throws another exception. Do I configure wrong in something?

Comment: Share your spring-context or jbo-context configuration.xml files?

Comment: I'm do not use any xml config. All configure use annotation @Bean.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleJobServiceFactoryBean needs to be populated with other mandatory properties to create a Jobservice.

```
@Bean
public JobService jobService() throws Exception {

    SimpleJobServiceFactoryBean factoryBean = new SimpleJobServiceFactoryBean();

    factoryBean.setDataSource(new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().build());

    factoryBean.setJobRepository((JobRepository) new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(
            new ResourcelessTransactionManager()).getObject());

    factoryBean.setJobLocator(new MapJobRegistry());

    factoryBean.setJobLauncher(new SimpleJobLauncher());

    factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factoryBean.getObject();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it.

Comment: It runs fine. But when i test this function jobService.listJobExecutions(int,int), it throws exception org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.
Do I need configure about datasource or something? I use mysql for database.

Comment: yes. you have to configure your MySQL database datasource, In the above example, an embedded database is used.

Comment: When i run job, it still save info about job execution into BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION table.

Comment: I use @Autowried Datasource, and add it to factoryBean. It works. Thank you so much!